# accessing elements of dynamiclly allocated array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to access the next element in dynamically allocated by adding the size of placeholder array to the first element. Size of placeholder array is 4 bytes, so if I add 4 bytes to it first element with address 2147549788, I should be looking at next memory location 2147549792. But, instead I'm looking at an address in 16 bytes 2147549804. If I read the address of array elements directly I get the right address. Wondering why adding size of placeholder gives different results ? 
Also, if I access the location of second element outside the for loop, the location is off by another 16 bytes i.e 2147549820

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Section {
    int numOfStudents;
} Section;

typedef struct School {
    int schoolId;
    Section sections[1]; //placeholder
} School;

int main(void) 
{
    School *schoolA_p;  
    Section section1;
    int sizeOffset = 0;
    int i,sectionSize;

    int sizeOfSchool = sizeof(School) - sizeof(Section) + (sizeof(Section)*2);
    schoolA_p = (struct School *) malloc(sizeOfSchool);

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        sectionSize = sizeof(Section);

        printf("\nsize of section = %d\n", sizeof(Section));
        printf("Number of bytes to add to first element to access the next element = %d\n", sizeOffset);
        printf("In Loop Location of schoolA_p->sections[%d]= 0x%lx\n",i, &(schoolA_p->sections[0]) + sizeOffset);

        sizeOffset += sectionSize;
    }

    printf("\n Location of schoolA_p->sections[0]= 0x%lx\n",&(schoolA_p->sections[0]));
    printf("\n Location of schoolA_p->sections[1]= 0x%lx\n",&(schoolA_p->sections[1]));

    printf("\n Outside of lopop Location of schoolA_p->sections[0]= 0x%lx\n", &(schoolA_p->sections[0])+ sizeOffset);

    free(schoolA_p); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On the inloop call, you forgot the &. schoolA_p->sections[0] -> &schoolA_p->sections[0] .

Comment: @jas can you share the o/p you are getting?

Comment: Assuming that the forgotten "&" is a typo in the question, aren't you just forgetting that C pointer arithmetic takes into account the size of the items? So p + 4 steps 4 _data objects_ forward, not 4 bytes.

Comment: You should use format specifier `%p` to print a pointer, which should be cast to `void*` such as `printf("%p",(void*)ptr)`

Comment: I forgot &. But I guess the issue was pointer arithmetic, I was assuming it to be 4 bytes forward. Didn't realise it will be 4 data objects forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic works like this: If `p` is a pointer to an array element `a[n]`, then `p + i` is a pointer to `a[n + i]`. In other words, pointer arithmetic moves in units of whatever base type the pointer is declared as, not bytes.

Answer (score 1):

C pointer arithmetic takes into account the size of the data pointed to when you increment a pointer.

So if `p` is a pointer to data of 4 bytes, `p + 1` calculates the address 4 bytes after `p`.

In other words, your doing too much work. C does this bookkeeping for you, and that's why you're getting incorrect results.

As a side note, this is why you cannot use pointer arithmetic on `void*` pointers. The size of the data pointed to is not specified.

Comment: Side side note: gcc allows arithmetic on `void *` as an extension (treating it like `char *`).

Comment: @melpomene I didn't know that. That's pretty interesting actually. It seems really  unsafe, and I would never recommend doing that, but C is not really a "safe" language anyway.